# How to show message if category exist in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I had a function to check categories is exist or not. But here I am facing one issue when check for duplicate category it is working fine.

but when call this one in template it now working fine.

```
                 <template v-slot:no-data>
                    <v-list>
                      <v-list-item  v-if="checkForDuplicateCategory()">
                        Duplicate entries not permitted
                      </v-list-item>
                      <v-list-item v-else>
                        No results matching "<strong>{{ bid.search }}</strong
                        >" . Press <kbd>enter</kbd> to create a new one
                      </v-list-item>
                    </v-list>
                  </template>
```

function is

```
 checkForDuplicateCategory(bool){
  console.log("Entered to check duplicate categories");
  let newEstimates = this.newEstimates.map((estimate) => {
    return estimate.category?.toLowerCase();
  });
  console.log("New Estimates" , newEstimates);
  if (newEstimates.includes(this.bid.category?.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here my scenario is when category exist it has to show like this **Duplicate entries not permitted** else it has show like this **Press enter to create a new one**

Comment: Is this a method? If yes, use computed instead.

Comment: Can you tell us what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @Amini i am tried with computed property also it not coming as expected

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim i had categories dropdown first i had selected Appliances and added next time when i try to add same category Appliances it has to show like Duplicate entries not permitted

Comment: It doesn't seem your code has problems. Check if you're mapping through `newEstimates` correctly and `bid` is true.

Comment: @Amini I had consoled newEstimates and bid those are coming correctly

Comment: can you at least show what's the console.log look like, and just try to debug it easily by print the value of `checkForDuplicateCategory` to the screen like {{ checkForDuplicateCategory }}. What's the current result on your screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use *Strict equality* instead of *includes()*.

```
checkForDuplicateCategory(){
  this.newEstimates.map((estimate) => {
    return estimate.category?.toLowerCase() === this.bid.category?.toLowerCase()
  });
}
```

Comment: Note: You should also map through `bid` if it's iterable.